# Enter the passcode you use to unlock the iPad - what is it?

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes, ipad, unlock

I am trying to connect to iTunes from my MacBook and it asks me "the passcode you use to unlock the iPad" and naminf my iPad.

Questions:

1. Does this mean that pin code pin code, which I use on iPad?
2. How can MacBook know it? Is it sended to Apple?
3. I am using Russian letters to unlock iPad, but on MacBook it is not possible to switch to Russian input. How can I enter unlock code then?

---

I have changed my unlock code to English letters, but this didn't help. Why do they need all moy codes?!

Comment: This might need to be spun off to separate questions, linked to each other. Let me know if you want help doing this.

Answer (score 0):

1. it is the pin code to unlock the iPad
2. MacBook only "knows" that the iPad has been unlocked. Pin is not sent to Apple.

Not necessary for connecting iPad and MacBook, but anyway: if you want to install Russian letters on MacBook, go to SystemPreferences > Keyboard > Input Sources (4th Tab from left side). Hit the [+] Button below left column and choose Russian.

Comment: I have russian letters on MacBook, but they are greyed out when entering passcode